# ASP.NET Core Web API : basic code works but responds with 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

We have this ASP.NET Core Web API based application developed using Visual Studio 2022.

The API will get request from devices with some JSON data and write to individual data files.

```
public IActionResult UpdateTestData([FromBody] InfoNegozio value)
{
    string str_rec = value.p1 + ";'" + value.p2 + "';" + value.p3 + ";" + value.p4 + ";" + value.p5 + ";" + value.p6 + "\n";

    string webRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
    string contentRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
    string data_file = "";
    string tmp1 = value.p2.Replace(" ", "_");
    string tmp2 = tmp1.Replace("-", "");
    string f_timestamp = tmp2.Replace(":", "");
    string fname = value.p1 + "_" + f_timestamp + ".txt";

    data_file = Path.Combine("D:\\test1\\test_data", "t1", fname);

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(data_file, str_rec);

    return Content("{\"status\":\"success\",\"Message\":\"Successfully stored\"}", "application/json");
}

public class InfoNegozio
{
    public string p1 { get; set; }
    public string p2 { get; set; }
    public float p3 { get; set; }
    public float p4 { get; set; }
    public float p5 { get; set; }
    public float p6 { get; set; }
}
```

In production IIS server version 10, .NET Core, the application worked perfectly fine for over a year. The devices used to get 200-OK response.

Now suddenly, we are getting HTTP 500 - internal server error.

The IIS log file shows all requests responded with Http code 500 error.

But, the JSON data that have been sent are being written to file and we could see the files in the specified directory in server.

Only thing the clients are not getting the 'Success' response. Instead it's an http 500 error.

In `web.config`, `stdoutLogEnabled` is 'true' .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\TestAPI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 250D451C-2WEC4-45E5-8DC6-6F342D456749BB2-->
```

We could see some 3 log files, but only entry there is

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestAPI\
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
```

We tried to make a request from Postman desktop application with content type `application/json`.The request to `UpdateTestData` method works perfectly fine. The data is written to a file on the server and we are also getting 'success' response.

Any inputs on what might be causing this 500 server error even after writing the data to file will be very helpful.

Thank you

**Update : 04-02-2024**

Thanks for the response.

1. I tried to put try-catch block and write the out put to log file.

   try
   {
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(data_file, str_rec);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(err_file))
   {
   sw.WriteLine("Error Message: " + ex.Message);
   sw.WriteLine("Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace);
   }
   throw;
   }

Tested this in development environment for known error and confirmed file writing. Deployed the code in Production environment. But no exception is raised. No log is written. Still the IIS gives 500 Internal server error.

2. In the web.config, tried to enable detailed logging.

   ```
     <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\TestAPI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
   <environmentVariables>
     <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
     <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS" value="true" />
   </environmentVariables>
   ```

   But no info is logged here as well.

   3. IIS log entry

   date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken

   2024-01-30 00:00:00 192.168.23.26 POST /Test/Test1 - 8085 - 106.209.214.171 - - 500 0 0 116

   4. As I mentioned in original post, Request raised through Postman desktop application works.
      I tried to get the request sent by Postman.

   "Request Headers": {
   "content-type": "application/json",
   "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.36.1",
   "accept": "*/*",
   "cache-control": "no-cache",
   "postman-token": "2ee6b117-de38-4e8f-b6ff-5d5c7ff8b3f5",
   "host": "xx.yy.zz.nn:8085",
   "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
   "connection": "keep-alive",
   "content-length": "197"

   5. This production server where web API is deployed has other applications belonging to client
      Right now, whenever changes are done we restart only our site. Not the entire IIS.
      Is this enough to reflect any changes ?
   6. No entry in windows event log regarding this IIS 500 error.

Comment: I really think you have no other choice than _debug_ your application. Maybe add a "unhandled exception" handler that writes a separate logfile ... But if you see the expected files sucessfully written, it is probably something that happens _after_ the `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(data_file, str_rec);` line ... but without further details it is impossible to tell what's wrong exactly.

Comment: Unrelated: "p1, p2" ... is immensely poor naming ...

Comment: If it is convenient for you to modify this project that has been running for a year, you can try to use try...catch... to monitor `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(data_file, str_rec);`. Or add some log-related configurations .

Comment: If you can't change your code and settings, we need to check the EventViewer Logs to find more details. By the way, the next time you [should remember the error sub code, it's also useful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-500-19-webpage).